# Problem with list search in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am using search option in the list . There is provision to add new items to the list. The problem is that when I add a new item to the list, the list is getting updated , but I cannot search that item through the search field. But after refreshing the browser, we can. But it is not possible to refresh browser each time....... Is there any solution for this problem?

Here is the code I am using to search the list.

```
xtype: 'searchfield',
placeHolder: 'Search',
name: 'searchfield',
id:'subListSearch',
listeners : {
scope: this,
'focus': function() {
Ext.getCmp('xbtn').show();

},

keyup: function(field) {

var value = field.getValue();

if (!value) {
Store.filterBy(function() {
return true;
});
} else {

var searches = value.split(' '),
regexps = [],
i;

for (i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
if (!searches[i]) return;
regexps.push(new RegExp(searches[i], 'i'));
};

Store.filterBy(function(record) {
var matched = [];

for (i = 0; i < regexps.length; i++) {
var search = regexps[i];

if (record.get('Name').match(search)) matched.push(true);
else matched.push(false);
};

if (regexps.length > 1 && matched.indexOf(false) != -1) {
return false;
} else {
return matched[0];
}
});
}
}
}
```

There is also some other problems. I using some provision to filter the list. But when I uses the search option, it is searching through the entire list, not the filtered list.why?

Thanks

Arun A G

Comment: What do you mean by searching?

Comment: Hi Luis,                                                                                I have to filter the list according to the keyword we are entering in the search bar

Comment: Which sencha version are you using.
I am trying to use the same example in sencha 2.0 bt its not working. I managed to display list and the searchfield.
However when I enter anything into searchfield it gives an error. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValue'
On below line
keyup: function(field) {
var value = field.getValue(); To get the example run, I did a trick.
Instead of using getValue() function I tried something different as
var value = String.fromCharCode(field.browserEvent.keyCode); now am getting value=the searchstring I put and after that it doe the proces

Comment: Hi Vaishali,I can retrieve the value from search field and it working correctly. The problem is that after adding the new item we cannot search it.... I solved it with bindStore() method in store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding to my question .
 The problem is fixed with bindStore() method. Earlier I was doing load() method to render the new data into the store. But we can not search the last entered item with this method. After binding the Changed store into the list with bindStore() method, the issue was solved.